# Populate inputs onInit with Form Builder

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to set values onInit using Form Builer and a `.forEach` loop but can't seem to make it work.
Basically when you click on the previous page project link you enter a project which can have already some values inside.

I'm getting all the datas from the existing project and they should be presetted onInit on the page, for example if in the **Drop** categorie the user had already registered values, they should appear ( for example in the red circle as quantité and Longueur )

[image]

But I can't make it work properly with the datas I receive. 
Every product line have a single ID which correspond to the following picture Index

Array with index as the product ID + values from the product --> Named in code as `quotDetails2` which should populate the inputs

[image]

So what I'm trying to achiev here is : make every product ID correspond to the Index values of my JSON and link them so the product with the good ID will render his values inside **longueur** & **quantity** in the HTML.

**CODE SAMPLE :**

**Component.ts**

```
import {Component, Input, OnChanges, OnInit, Output} from '@angular/core';
import {FormArray, FormBuilder, ReactiveFormsModule, FormGroup} from '@angular/forms';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import {ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router';
import {QuotationMenuService} from '../../quotation-menu.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-drops',
  templateUrl: './drops.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./drops.component.scss']
})
export class DropsComponent implements OnChanges,OnInit {

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
              private httpClient: HttpClient,
              private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
              private service: QuotationMenuService
  ) {



  }

  @Input()dataDynLevel: Event;
  @Input()dataDynParts: Event;
  @Input()quotationId: Event;


  dataDiam1: any;
  dataDiam2: any;


  quotationIdNumber: any;
  dropForm: FormGroup;
  quotArray: any;
  filteredWithDiam: any;
  token = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('token'));
  projectId : any;
  part_id: any;
  urlSegment = this.activatedRoute.pathFromRoot[1].url.subscribe(val => this.projectId = val[1].path);
  quotDetails: any;
  quotDetails2: any;
  indexInputs : number;
  concatArrays: any;
  arrayWithValues: Array<any>;
  copy: any;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.requiredFields();
    this.initQuot()
  }

  get f() {
    return this.dropForm.controls;
  }

  get longueur(): FormArray{
    return this.dropForm.get('longueur') as FormArray;
  }


  requiredFields(){
    this.dropForm = this.formBuilder.group(
      {
        diameter1: [''],
        diameter2: [''],
        quantity: [''],
        longueur: ['']
      }
    )

  }



  ngOnChanges() {
    this.filterDrop();
    this.initQuot();
  }

  initQuot() {
    this.service.checkExistQuot().subscribe(res => {
      this.quotArray = res;
      this.quotDetails = res.quotation.quotationdetail;
      this.quotDetails2 = res.quotation.quotationdetail2;
      this.quotDetails.forEach( (myArray, index) => {
        this.copy.forEach( array1Ttem => {
          console.log(this.quotDetails2, "DETAILS");
          this.quotDetails.forEach( array2Item => {

            if(this.quotDetails2[index] == array2Item.part_id){
              for (var i = 0; i < this.copy.length; i++) {
                let patchValue = {};
                this.copy[i].longueur = this.quotDetails2[array1Ttem.part_id].longueur;
                this.copy[i].quantity = myArray.quantity;
                patchValue[`longueur`] = this.copy[index].longueur;
                patchValue[`quantity`] = this.copy[index].quantity;
                this.dropForm.patchValue(patchValue);
              }
            }
            else{

            }

          })
        });
      })
    })
  }


  postQuotationDatas(id, index){
    console.log(index);
    this.part_id = id;
    this.service.part_id = this.part_id;
    this.service.part_type = "drop";
    this.service.quantity = this.dropForm.get(`quantity_${index}`).value;
    this.service.longueur = this.dropForm.get(`longueur_${index}`).value;
    this.service.postQuotationDatas();
  }

  filterDrop(){
    this.dataDiam1 = this.dataDynParts;
    let dynDiam1 = this.dataDiam1.map(function (obj) {
      return obj.diam[0];
    });
    dynDiam1 = dynDiam1.filter(function(v,i) { return dynDiam1.indexOf(v) == i; });
    this.dataDiam1 = dynDiam1;


    this.dataDiam2 = this.dataDynParts;
    let dynDiam2 = this.dataDiam2.map(function (obj) {
      return obj.diam[1];
    });
    dynDiam2 = dynDiam2.filter(function(v,i) { return dynDiam2.indexOf(v) == i; });
    this.dataDiam2 = dynDiam2;
    /*    console.log(dynDiam2);*/

    this.requiredFields();
    /*    console.log(this.dataDynLevel);
        console.log(this.dataDynParts);*/
    this.filteredWithDiam = this.dataDynParts;
    this.selectedDiam = this.dataDynParts;
    this.copy = this.selectedDiam;
    /*console.log(this.quotationId);*/
    this.quotationIdNumber = this.quotationId;
  }



}
```

**Component.html**

```
<div class="container wid">
  <form [formGroup]="dropForm">
    <div class="desc d-flex flex-row">
      <a class="flex1 bold">Photo</a>
      <a class="flex1 bold">Catégorie</a>
      <div class="flex-nowrap flex1">
        <label for="diam1" class="bold">ø Drops</label>
        <select id="diam1" (click)="filterDiam1()"  formControlName="diameter1" class="ml-1 form-control diam">
          <option value="">All</option>
          <option  [value]="diam1" *ngFor="let diam1 of dataDiam1">{{diam1}}</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="flex1">
        <label for="diam2" class="bold">ø Outlet</label>
        <select id="diam2" (click)="filterDiam()" formControlName="diameter2" class="ml-1 form-control diam">
          <option value="">All</option>
          <option *ngFor="let diam2 of dataDiam2">{{diam2}}</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <a class="flex1 bold">Longueur</a>
      <a class="flex1 tac bold">Vanne</a>
      <a class="flex1 bold">Prix Unitaire</a>
      <a class="flex1 bold">Quantité</a>
      <a class="flex1 tac bold">Total</a>
    </div>
    <div class="products">
      <div class="d-flex flex-row" *ngFor="let products of copy; let  i = index;">
        <a class="flex1">Photo</a>
        <a class="flex1">{{products.l3_label}} , {{products.part_id}}</a>
        <a class="flex1">{{products.diam[0]}}</a>
        <a class="flex1">{{products.diam[1]}}</a>
        <a class="flex1">
          <input class="number"  formControlName="longueur" value=""  (change)="postQuotationDatas(products.part_id,i)" type="number">
        </a>
        <input class="mb-1 flex1 checkbox" type="checkbox">
        <a class="tac flex1"></a>
        <a class="flex1 mb-1">
          <input class="number" value=""  formControlName="quantity" (change)="postQuotationDatas(products.part_id, i)" type="number">
        </a>
        <a class="flex1"></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Thank you in advance for your help !

Comment: When you build the form using `FormBuilder`, you can provide initial values to the controls. See https://angular.io/api/forms/FormBuilder for more information.

Comment: Can you create a stackblitz?

Comment: @Zephyr, what data you has? what data you need? why not use a FormArray?

Comment: @David I'm trying but it's pretty tricky, sending it when it's working

Comment: Feels like https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-sub-form might help here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `[(ngModel)]` instead of `value` on your input-fields:

```
<input class="number" formControlName="longueur" [(ngModel)]="products.longueur"  
    (change)="postQuotationDatas(products.part_id, i)" type="number">

<input class="number" formControlName="quantity" [(ngModel)]="products.quantity"
    (change)="postQuotationDatas(products.part_id, i)" type="number">
```

If you reach this code and it works correctly they should be set:

```
this.copy[i].longueur = this.quotDetails2[array1Ttem.part_id].longueur;
this.copy[i].quantity = myArray.quantity;
```

By the way, I think you can just pass in `products` to this function, and get what you need from that:

```
postQuotationDatas(products){
  this.part_id = products.part_id;
  this.service.part_id = this.part_id;
  this.service.part_type = "drop";
  this.service.quantity = products.quantity;
  this.service.longueur = products.longueur;
  this.service.postQuotationDatas();
}
```

Comment: Why using `ngModel` while using Reactive Forms?

Comment: @JoH To me this seem like the easiest approach. Else create a `FormGroup` for every item. Seem cumbersome to keep track of all indexes etc.

Comment: @Arg0n When I use NgModel with Form Control I get a warning that says it's deprecated, does it still works ? Can update the question with a screenshot of the warning if you want. And just to let you know, it still remain as a blank using NgModel there, no changes

Comment: @JoH For you I should create a `FormGroup` for every data ?

Comment: I think so. When I see your HTML,  I think you should refactor it into a table, it should be easier to populate your inputs.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create a new control for each row, and push it to a FormArray control. Also make sure your form is properly connected in the template by adding the control names in the correct location.

I've created a small demo which also contains some more info:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-u9gtmm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts